# Dependency: Microsoft Word?

Tags: c#, .net, web

I have written a small app that I am distributing to some of my friends.  It interacts with web pages and the only dependancy I would consider odd is Microsoft.mshtml.dll to interact with some web controls.

We have noticed an odd behavior that on some computers it worked and on others it didn't.  I told them all to make sure to install the .Net 4.0 Framework FULL and not client profile.  It still didn't work.

One of my friends noticed that the machines of his it did work on had Microsoft Word installed, the others did not.  So he installed a trial version and magically, my program started to work!

What is installed with Microsoft Word that isn't in the .Net Framework?  Is there any way I can send them the needed files?

Note: I was originally using an installer, and it worked fine, but I couldn't figure out how to update the application so we fell back to me just shipping them the app in a zip.  So please, do not answer by saying "make an installer project".  I'm currently trying to figure out how to make an updater, that is not the topic of discussion here.

Thanks!

Edit:  I have not *knowingly* added any dependancy to Word...

Comment: What are you depending on mshtml for?  What does it do? When you say interacts with web pages, do you mean it screen scrapes other pages? Manipulates other pages?   I don't believe Microsoft.mshtml.dll is part of the .net framework, and is probably installed by office.  You may have to make sure this dll is copied to your output directory and shipped with your app (not sure about the licensing requirements though).

Comment: Did you distribute *all* of the DLLs that were alongside your app when it was built? Visual Studio should have moved all of the required DLLs into the project's bin\Release directory. Perhaps the 'Copy Local' property of the missing dependency is set to false, so it never gets copied to the output directory...?

Comment: Here's a for-instance: ClickLink(HtmlElement linkToClick) { HTMLAnchorElementClass linkElement = (HTMLAnchorElementClass)linkToClick.DomElement; linkElement.click(); } The HTMLAnchorElementClass is in mshtml.

Comment: did you distribute the Microsoft.mshtml.dll with your application in the apps bin folder?  http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/212262/Csharp-net-application-which-is-referencing-Micros

Comment: You mention that when you made an installer that it worked, look at the dependency's of your old installer to determine what might be missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you're using some libraries like Microsoft.mshtml.dll which are not part of .Net framework but are of Native .Net then there are chances that target machine is lacking for those libraries. For e.g. Microsoft.mshtml.dll comes with your Visual studio tools for office support etc. so if Office/Visual Studio is not installed on the target machine then application will not work.

As an alternative solution identify them and keep the local copy of these dependent dll's and ship them in your package. But this is not a best practice.

But Paul_R said it right. Identify your client infrastructure, plan and Test once(on target environment) before releasing it. Keep in mind that you have a Developer machine but others not.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's best to avoid dependencies on other applications. So, try to avoid using the methods/data structures that are offered by that library. Chances are there is a library native to .NET that will do what you're looking for. If not, look for some open source libraries that you can easily include with your application in the form of a .dll (you can even tell it to attach itself to the application in many cases). If you're doing some html parsing, I fully recommend HTMLAgilityPack (http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question you're asking: 
A LOT is installed with Word that is not installed with the .NET Framework. Word is very complex application.

In theory, yes, you might be able to send them the needed files. 
In practice, you'd manually recreate half a Word installation, plus infringe copyright. Please don't.

I agree with Paul_R: Try to avoid the dependency if your "customers" are not Word users.

Answer (score 0):

> What is installed with Microsoft Word that isn't in the .Net
>   Framework?

The Microsoft Word application itself and all of it's supporting files.

> Is there any way I can send them the needed files?

Yes.  However, there are a few things you need to consider before proceeding.

- It may be illegal to redistribute some of the things you have a dependency on.  Tread carefully here and do your research before you proceed.
- If you rely on the system having the dependencies which are needed, you'll have problems with the dependencies not existing, or other versions of the dependencies existing.

Safest bet, is to find something light-weight and freely redistributable which has the functionality you need, not Microsoft Word.

Alternatively, you could have your application disable the functionality which uses dependencies that may not be present.

**Edit**:  If you're going to deploy the dependencies, it is just a matter of identifying  them and ensuring they are packaged.  Tools like .NET Reflector are great for identifying all of the downstream dependencies.